# SQL timestamp to specific hour

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I need to set the time of a timestamp in SQL.
My results need to be between yesterday at 7 o'clock and today at 7 o'clock.

Here is the query

```
WHERE created_at BETWEEN 
    ?::timestamp - INTERVAL '1 day' AND ?::timestamp 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

The value is:

```
2017-05-30
```

I've seen the PostgreSQL datetime functions. But I don't know how to specify a time

---

Here is the query with static datetimes

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    "myTable" 
WHERE 
    created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-30 07:00:00' AND '2017-05-30 07:00:00'
ORDER BY 
    created_at DESC
```

Now I need to replace the datetime strings with a date string and add the time in SQL

Comment: `created_at BETWEEN '2017-05-30 07:00:00' AND '2017-05-30 07:00:00'` is effectively the same as `created_at = '2017-05-30 07:00:00'` did you mean `BETWEEN '2017-05-29 07:00:00' AND '2017-05-30 07:00:00'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `current_date` (without a time) and then add the 7 hours:

```
WHERE created_at BETWEEN (current_date - 1) + time '07:00:00' 
                     AND current_date + time '07:00:00'
```

`(current_date - 1)` is "yesterday"

Alternatively you could use an interval:

```
WHERE created_at BETWEEN (current_date - 1) + interval '7' hour
                     AND current_date + interval '7' hour
```

I prefer adding a "time" as that is easier to write if you also want to include minutes, e.g. `current_date + time '07:30:00'`

Comment: Beware that this will give the wrong answer on the days when Daylight Saving Time begins and ends.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't give any sample data, I based it on create date on databases.

```
select name, datediff(day, create_date, getdate()) DaysDiff from sys.databases
**where DATEDIFF(DAY, create_date,getdate()) > 1**
```

You'll need to evaluate days difference, something like:

```
where DATEDIFF(DAY, create_at, getdate()) > 1
```

Comment: I added a sample how it looks with static strings

Comment: There is  no `datediff()` in Postgres (or "SQL")

Comment: OK, was confused by tags and OP wording.